# Avoid making .babelrc file to use for testing with Jest

Tags: babeljs, jestjs, babel-jest

I realize that it is recommended to make a `.babelrc` file to run tests with Jest according to [their docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html#babel-integration).  But is there any way I could load the babelrc config programmatically and therefore not have to create this file for every React project that I have?  Also, I realize I could put something in my `package.json` file, but I don't want to have to do that either.

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of Jest's [scriptPreprocessor](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#scriptpreprocessor-string) config setting.  I created a file that looked like this and it worked:

```
const babel = require('babel-core')
const jestPreset = require('babel-preset-jest')

module.exports = {
  process: function (src) {
    const transformCfg = {
      presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0', jestPreset],
      retainLines: true
    }
    return babel.transform(src, transformCfg).code
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I already have a .babelrc file used for something else. I dont want jest to refer that and instead read config from some other file as the one you created above. Is that possible?

Comment: Update 2017 - You should place the contents above in a `preprocessor.js` file and then reference it from the `transform` option (`scriptPreprocessor'` has been removed). Complete example [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/typescript/package.json)